# Mailjet API: /bouncestatistics endpoint not working

Tags: mailjet

Whenever I query the [Mailjet /bouncestatistics endpoint](https://dev.mailjet.com/email/reference/message-events/#v3_get_bouncestatistics) with no query parameters, I always get an empty set returned.

```
{
    "Count": 0,
    "Data": [],
    "Total": 0
}
```

This is despite me having several bounced messages after 00:00 UTC on the current day, e.g. user not found.

Has anyone else seen this too?

Comment: Are you using any Library? I just had to do the same thing and thought it is not working. When using the official PHP Library you need to apply the query parameters with the `filters` parameter, which was first confusing for me.

Comment: @Tuxes3 no, I was not using a library, I was simply loading the endpoint with valid authentication and no parameters. I'm not using Mailjet anymore so I can't test further.